# Fabric JS - making collage under PNG mask

Tags: svg, png, fabricjs, mask, layer

Our team is working on creating an online collage.
[https://jsfiddle.net/Lfz1bp7r/3/]

Characteristically, the collage should be under the mask of the PNG file. At this stage we are trying different libraries. Attention on fabricJS. The collage scheme is implemented using SVG paths. The first problem was tracking mouse events in SVG pathways. Implemented manually. The main problem is to add a new picture, which should be above the collage but below the mask. Manipulations with globalCompositeOperation do not help. There are no layers in the fabricJS.

So the question is - will the fabricJS allow you to implement the addition of a new picture on top of the collage, but under the PNG mask? It's possible?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FabricJS includes two ways to draw on top of the canvas above the standard object and controls layers. You can set an [overlayImage](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#overlayImage), and you can use the `after:render` event to run additional draw commands on the canvas context. See the [Bounding Rectangle demo](http://fabricjs.com/bounding-rectangle) for a simple example of how to do this.

See [How Fabric Canvas Layering Works](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/How-fabric-canvas-layering-works).

Comment: Biggest thanks!!! OverlayImage - its that I searched!!!

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer as correct if it answers your question.